# 403 error on put of sharepoint file works in graph explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a file upload put string that works great in graph explorer but does not work in my python script. I have the same application permissions for both. I'm getting a 403 permissions error in the python script.

I'm trying to modify MicroSoft's python-sample-console-app to upload a file to Sharepoint and not OneDrive. I did add the Sharepoint permissions after I got the original sample app working.

I guess that isn't much to go on. My question is why can I do the put command in graph explorer but not my app.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can state a few things:
which endpoint exactly are you connection to?   
which permissions are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python-sample-console-app](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-console-app) uses delegated [permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference), make sure you did enter in your app delegated permissions and not application permissions.
Also check if your operations are available in a delegated scenario (token obtained [on behalf of a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user))
e.g. Access to another users non-shared mailfolder may not be possible in a delegated scenario.

In Assumption that you did enter the correct permissions in your application.

It seems that you are still using an old token, the one from your previous test which does not contain your added permission(s).
Every time you change the permissions of your app you need to repeat the [Authorization](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user#2-get-authorization)/[Admin](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service#3-get-administrator-consent)-consent.

Try to repeat your consent, then fetch a new token and check if the problem still persists.
You can also look into your current token (its a [JSONWebToken](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519), [azure-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims)) and see if it contains your permissions.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to figure out how to repeat the consent. I ended up creating a new application and it fixed the issue.